# VSTO Excel Add-in Caching issue and Load Behavior settings?

Tags: c#, excel, caching, vsto

The strange problem I am having now is the Excel 2010 Add-in won't let me use the newer version. For some reason, it is still pointing to the old version and displaying the old UI.So my first impression about this is perhaps Excel caches stuff in the background or something.

This problem seems to be disappeared if I set the Add-in LoadBehavior value to 16 or 3 instead of 9 (the default value is set to 9). But I am not sure if it's a fix or probably I just somehow get lucky. Anyway, I hope someone can help explain a bit further about this problem. Thanks.

Comment: How are you deploying the Add-In? ClickOnce, MSI, Visual Studio, etc.?

Comment: What does your manifest key look like? Please share the registry hive and platform for OS and Office.

Comment: Well target platform is 32bit OS and OFfice 2007/2010. Also I've noticed something under this subkey, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{MYCLSID}\InprocServer32\  There appears to be multiple subkeys representing multiple assembly versions, e.g. 1.0.0.0 to start with, and then 1.0.4330.314, and so on. So is it normal to have them there? Seems that every time I install a new version, the new subkey with new version number will be created, while the older ones are still remained.

Comment: You should share your registry hive (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\[pluginName]`), along with the `Manifest` key value at this hive.

Comment: Sure. Here it is: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\MyExcelAddin,  Manifest Key value = `C:\Program Files\MyExcelAddinInstallation\MyExcelAddin.vsto|vstolocal`, LoadBehavior value = 9

Answer (score 0):

Have you appended "|vsto" to manifest path (check registry software/microsoft/office/exce/addins/[your addin name]/manifest. if this is not done vsto will always pick dll from clickone cache